# strange 404 error in djangocms when using details view

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I have got an 404 error with djangocms, Raised by: cms.views.details.

I am trying to insert an external app in django CMS. When I run the app separately I dont have the 404 error on my detail view, all is working fine. But when I put my apps in djangocms, please note that the listview works fine and the detail view makes the 404 error.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

djangocms version 3.2
django 1.9
python 3.4

here the url.py of my external app

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from . import views
from .views import DocListView, DocDetailView

app_name = 'inventaire'
urlpatterns = patterns('',

url(r'^document/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DocDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),

url(r'^document$', views.DocListView.as_view(), name='index'),
)
```

Here the views

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic
from .models import Document, Mention

# Create your views here.

class DocListView(generic.ListView):
template_name = 'inventaire/index.html'
context_object_name = 'latest_document_list'

def get_queryset(self):
    """Return the last five published questions."""
    return Document.objects.all


class DocDetailView(generic.DetailView):
model = Document
template_name = 'inventaire/detail.html'
```

here my url.py from my cms

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function, unicode_literals

from cms.sitemaps import CMSSitemap
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import *  # NOQA
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),  # NOQA
url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap',
    {'sitemaps': {'cmspages': CMSSitemap}}),
url(r'^select2/', include('django_select2.urls')),
url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
url(r'^inventaire/', include('testTemplates.apps.inventaire.urls')),
)

# This is only needed when using runserver.
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',  # NOQA
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    ) + staticfiles_urlpatterns() + urlpatterns  # NOQA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'cms.urls'` include must be the last in your urlpatterns. It will catch all requests, so move your `'inventaire/'` include above that.

Comment: You save hours to me. Ok as that's wrote here : http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.4.2/getting_started/tutorial.html You need to include the 'cms.urls' urlpatterns at the end of your urlpatterns.